# Remove default Jquery Datatable search event and add custome event

Tags: jquery, events, datatables

I am using Jquery Data-table and my table has server-side process, because of that I'm willing to turn default search action (which sends a request per key-up) off and use my own action. 
I tried these things but none work:

```js
table.search( '' );
```

```js
table.one( 'search.dt', function (event) { //my action here})
```

```js
table.off('search.dt')
table.off('search')
```

```js
$('my_table_selector').removeEventListener('search')
$('my_table_selector').removeEventListener('search.dt')
$('my_table_selector').unbind('search')
$('my_table_selector').unbind('search')
```

```js
table.on( 'search.dt', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
})
```

I understand that `js` does not overwrite listeners.
Could you please help me to overwrite data-table search action with my own action?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you Srudent  or Student?

Comment: a working code sample would help us see what you are trying to do and how we can help you out. you can use codepen or StackOverflow code snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your datatable's ID is "example", then assign it to a variable when you initialize it:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  // usual config in here
});
```

Then use something like this to redefine the related search box event:

```
$('#example_filter input').off().blur(function () {
  // your logic in here, for example:
  //table.search(this.value).draw();
});
```

In my example, I used `blur` (which fires when the search box loses focus), but you can replace that with whatever you need.

Note that my selector `'#example_filter input'` is based on the standard values provided by DataTables, together with the table ID. Unless you have customized the DataTable default classes, that approach should work.